# How to pass template text to bean from the JSF page

Tags: jsf

I have a check box that has a long description. I want to pass that description in the email if the user selected that check box.

I don't want to write the same description in the back end bean and the JSF page. Instead I want to pass the front end description to the bean.

How can I do this in JSF

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{contactUsBean.subscribeNewsLetter}" />
I would like to receive the news letters from the company abc.........
```

And this long lengthy description need to pass to bean.

Comment: Why don't you save it in the bean ?

Answer (score 0):

Put a span around what you want to grab with an id. On form submission grab the content with javascript and put it in an hidden input field and get it in the bean. Or, you know, just write it in the bean or a bundle and grab it there.

To grab it from a bundle file:

Create a package named "strings" or whatever you want to call it. Create a file named "strings.properties".

In it write your content :

```
Content=bla bla bla.
```

Then grab it from the file as such:

```
private final static String BUNDLE_BASENAME = "resources.strings.strings";
private ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_BASENAME,
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale());
String content = bundle.getString("Content");
```

To write it on your jsf page:

```
    <f:loadBundle basename="resources.strings.strings" var="pmsg" />

    #{pmsg.Content}
```

For the other method, the javascript is well documented but well:

```
myContentElem = document.getElementById("id");
myContent = myContentElem.innerHTML;
getElementById("hiddenInput").value = myContent;
```

Srsly put it in your bean or bundle, this is retarded. If you don't want to write it twice just use an EL expression so you don't write it in the jsf page.